# What does the phrase "add stakes" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

Here is a sentence from a platform game app:

> Without any doubt, it’s a great way to **add stakes** to the platforming.

The game has a revised gameplay in which a player can start from the most recent checkpoint and does not have to start from the very beginning if she loses her life by hitting danger.

The player has to jump and collect certain items. It's a one-tap game. The above-mentioned sentence precedes the sentences describing the new feature which allow the player to start from the most recent checkpoints in place of starting from the very beginning.

I am not sure which of the [meanings](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/stake_1) of the word stake fits here.

Comment: The added detail is very helpful. Which of the meanings that you linked do you think are the most likely to fit the meaning based on the text surrounding the sentence?

Comment: @ColleenV None of them seems to fit here unambiguously. The author may mean either "checkpoints" or the 2a sense of the word stake.

Comment: It helps the people answering to know what you’ve considered and discarded. You may want to edit your comment into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In context, it seems as though meaning 2a from the page you linked is most applicable. The sentence, however, is confusing, as it seems to state the opposite of the actual effect. Were I to read this sentence knowing only that the subject was a platforming game, I would certainly take it to mean that whatever feature was being described would increase the risk, in terms of either what is gained on a success or lost on a failure, of platforming well. The feature described, though, seems to have the exact opposite effect; from the information you give, I would guess that this sentence was intended to discuss the potential merits of turning *off* the checkpoint feature, and its incorrect placement or lack of context may have been a mistake by the developers.